# How do I return HTML from managed bean in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I have one method in my managed bean which returns javascript as a string. When the method is invoked from `head` tag, it works fine. But when it is invoked from `body`, the browser instead of rendering the javascript writes it as it is. What can be the problem?

In my JSF page when i do `#{IndexBean.EastRegionGadgets}` in `head` it works fine but it doesn't in `body`. It outputs the HTML as it is. Here is the code:

```
package BusinessFacade;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText;


enum REGION{
    NORTH,EAST,WEST;
}

class Gadget{
    private String gadgetCode = "";
    private REGION gadgetRegion = REGION.WEST;

    public Gadget(String gadgetCode, REGION gadgetRegion){
        this.gadgetCode = gadgetCode;
        this.gadgetRegion = gadgetRegion;
    }

    public String getGadgetCode() {
        return gadgetCode;
    }

    public void setGadgetCode(String gadgetCode) {
        this.gadgetCode = gadgetCode;
    }

    public REGION getGadgetRegion() {
        return gadgetRegion;
    }

    public void setGadgetRegion(REGION gadgetRegion) {
        this.gadgetRegion = gadgetRegion;
    }

}

@ManagedBean(name="IndexBean")
@RequestScoped
public class IndexBean {
    ArrayList<Gadget> _list;
    public IndexBean() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize(){
        _list = new ArrayList<Gadget>();
        Gadget objGadget = new Gadget("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn.widgetserver.com/syndication/subscriber/InsertWidget.js'></script><script>if (WIDGETBOX) WIDGETBOX.renderWidget('78d12c15-dc87-42f2-a78a-3f62a91a119a');</script><noscript>Get the <a href='http://www.widgetbox.com/widget/crystal-clock'>Crystal Clock</a> widget and many other <a href='http://www.widgetbox.com/'>great free widgets</a> at <a href='http://www.widgetbox.com'>Widgetbox</a>! Not seeing a widget? (<a href='http://docs.widgetbox.com/using-widgets/installing-widgets/why-cant-i-see-my-widget/'>More info</a>)</noscript>",REGION.WEST);
        _list.add(objGadget);

        objGadget = new Gadget("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn.widgetserver.com/syndication/subscriber/InsertWidget.js'></script><script>if (WIDGETBOX) WIDGETBOX.renderWidget('1ccc3dee-8266-4b84-8191-13a4bf584d0c');</script><noscript>Get the <a href='http://www.widgetbox.com/widget/custom-clock'>Shiny Clock</a> widget and many other <a href='http://www.widgetbox.com/'>great free widgets</a> at <a href='http://www.widgetbox.com'>Widgetbox</a>! Not seeing a widget? (<a href='http://docs.widgetbox.com/using-widgets/installing-widgets/why-cant-i-see-my-widget/'>More info</a>)</noscript>",REGION.EAST);
        _list.add(objGadget);



    }

    public String getWestRegionGadgets(){
        HtmlOutputText objHtmlOutputText = new HtmlOutputText();
        String strGadgets = "";
        for(Gadget objGadget:_list ){
            if(objGadget.getGadgetRegion() == REGION.WEST){
                strGadgets += objGadget.getGadgetCode();
            }
        }
        return strGadgets;

    }

    public String getEastRegionGadgets(){

        String strGadgets = "";
        for(Gadget objGadget:_list ){
            if(objGadget.getGadgetRegion() == REGION.EAST){
                strGadgets += objGadget.getGadgetCode();
            }
        }
        return strGadgets;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> *In my JSF page when i do `#{IndexBean.EastRegionGadgets}` in `head`  it works fine but it doesn't in `body`. It outputs the HTML as it is.*

I suppose you're using `<h:outputText>` in `body` to output the HTML. As per the [documentation](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/h/outputText.html) it by default escapes HTML. You need to set its `escape` attribute to `false`.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.html}" escape="false" />
```

Comment: No actually i was not using anything. I just wrote #{bean.html} in body and wrote everything in HTML. However, the same line worked fine in head tag!

Comment: Ah yes, you're using Facelets.

Comment: Yes i am using Facelets. Do i need to compulsorily use this outputText to output html? from managed bean?

Comment: Yes, it by default escapes inline EL in body as well. All just to prevent XSS.

Comment: The project I had to fix now, was using <f:verbatim>, for which the docs state it does NOT by default escape html. It did escape html. The above worked - thanks BalusC!