# Add html content to faces message from Backing Bean

Tags: jsf-2

I need to add a Html content when some method returns the wanted result (any method, any result) to the JSF page exactly like primefaces do with .

Html to add is simple :

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
                </div>
```

But can't find a way to do this cleanly, I've read many posts like [How do I return HTML from managed bean in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351639/how-do-i-return-html-from-managed-bean-in-jsf) but my bean need to insert that html when user is doing something e.g. submitting a form result.

**Also :** is there a way to save it and show it in case of a redirection like it is with primefaces     `context.getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply using h:messages tag ? It is fully customizable in terms of design and you can simply affect your styles and class without all the turn-around

Source : http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_messages.html

Comment: Thank you, this is an option, not an answer.